# pthread functions "_np" suffix

Tags: posix, pthreads, glibc

What does "_np" suffix mean here:

```
pthread_mutex_timedlock_np
```

or in macros

```
PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP
```

Upd:

From glibc2.2

```
enum 
{ 
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP, 
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP, 
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP, 
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP 
#ifdef __USE_UNIX98 
  , 
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL = PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP, 
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE = PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP, 
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK = PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK_NP, 
  PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT = PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL 
#endif 
#ifdef __USE_GNU 
  /* For compatibility. */ 
  , PTHREAD_MUTEX_FAST_NP = PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP 
#endif 
};
```

Does defining `__USE_UNIX98`
 change portability of _NP functions/macro?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Non standard extensions -- i.e., Non Portable. [ref (from the Internet Archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20090226221922/https://cs.pub.ro/~apc/2003/resources/pthreads/uguide/users-gu.htm)

Answer (score 8):

It stands for Non Portable.

That is, it's platform specific extensions to the standard pthreads functions.